# CSS size inter-dependency and resizing via JS in Chrome: possible bug?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I believe I may have found a bug in chrome, brought on by trying to resize a container in one axis (height, say) when the container's contents' size depends on that of the parent, and the container's width depends on that of the contents. Diagrammatically:

Container height → child height → child width → container width

Where an arrow indicates "influences."

The bug manifests when you change the container's height in javascript. The size of the child changes to reflect the container's size, but the container's width doesn't change until the *next* time the element is resized (other changes to the element can trigger this, too)

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<!doctype html5>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
doStuff = function() {
    div = document.getElementById('div');
    img = document.getElementById('img');
    button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (div.style.height == '200px') {
                div.style.height = '100px';
            } else {
                div.style.height = '200px';
            }
        });
};
</script>

<style>
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="doStuff();">
<h1>Test</h1>
<div id="div">
    <img id="img" src="http://fishface.org.uk/uploads/images/random/whybird.jpg" alt="why">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://fishface.org.uk/uploads/images/random/whybird.jpg" alt="why">
</div>
<p><button id="button">resize</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/4w9u6qwt/2/). As you can see, the div is given a fixed height and an automatic width, whilst the child - the image - is given height 100% (i.e. the height of the container) and an automatic width (i.e. scale proportionally with height.) When you resize the container in chrome, the height changes but the width remains the same. When you resize a second time, the height changes back and the width changes to what it *should* have been on the first resize. Behaviour on Firefox is as expected, and on modern IE, the width *never* changes.

So my question: is this really a bug in Chrome? Or am I doing something illegal in CSS? In either case, what's the workaround? In this simple example and in my actual case I could just resize the image instead, but let's suppose I absolutely have to resize the div - is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is a bug. To be more specific, it doesn't properly handles the resizing of an `inline` element(the `img`) inside the `inline-block` element while keeping proper aspect ratio.

As a *workaround* here, is just set the `display:block` for your image, and it will work as expected.

Lets inspect the behaviour: we have the image `300x317` showing in a `inline-blok` container `200xAuto` with resulting sizing *after maintaining the aspect ration*: `200x189`. Now changing the height of the container to `100xAuto` we get the resulting sizing `100x189`, but the child image was also resized due to keeping the aspect ratio. So I would say, the reason the container stays of the `100x189` size - is due to one path reflow downside, but if you set the image display to `block`, then in that scenario the image will cause the **`bottom-up` reflow**, and the container gets new sizing: instead of `100x189` it knows the correct size of the child and takes new dimension `100x93`.

Reflows are actually very expensive, so this *behaviour* is eventually due to optimizations of inline elements reflow triggers